# Variable reference into an HTML text/html type

Tags: javascript

In JS I assign 5 to variable myVar. Then I would like to pass this variable into an HTML text/html type and show it in my demonstration div. I fail since I get 'myVar' instead of 5. Could you please someone help me.

```
<script>
    myVar = 5
</script>

<script id="myBlock" type="text/html">myVar</script>

<div id="DemonstrationDiv"></div>

<script>
    vBlock = document.getElementById('myBlock');
    document.getElementById('DemonstrationDiv').innerHTML = vBlock.innerHTML
</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen a `<script>` tag used for `type='text/html'`. Seem illogical to me.

Comment: @StackSlave You can do that if you are in a browser that does not support `<template>`.

Comment: @StackSlave It is a way to pass HTML in JS. If you run it you will see that it works but i have problem with the variable. This example is a simplification of a complicated routine

Comment: Why not just use the variable instead? That's what they're for. Something like: `document.getElementById('DemonstrationDiv').textContent = myVar;`.

Comment: Doesn't look like `text/html` is the appropriate type here, so I think you're misusing it - there's got to be a better way to go about this but it's hard to tell why & what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you call `eval()` on `vBlock.innerHTML`

```html
<script>
    myVar = 5
</script>

<script id="myBlock" type="text/html">myVar</script>

<div id="DemonstrationDiv"></div>

<script>
    vBlock = document.getElementById('myBlock');
    document.getElementById('DemonstrationDiv').innerHTML = eval(vBlock.innerHTML)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
    myVar = 5
</script>

<script id="myBlock" type="text/html">{{myVar}} is {{myVar}}, and {{myVar}} should be 5</script>

<div id="DemonstrationDiv"></div>

<script>
  var template = document.getElementById('myBlock').innerHTML;
  
  document.getElementById('DemonstrationDiv').innerHTML = template.replace(/\{\{myVar\}\}/g, myVar);
</script>
```

If you are not going to be doing this a lot, you can write a one off that just replaces the string with the variable value.

If you are going to be doing this a lot though, I recommend looking into Handlebars or Mustache for a complete templating library.  The syntax I used here is similar to the patterns that they follow.